# convergence proof without finding 'N'

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to prove $\sqrt{n^2 +n}-n$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ I am not sure what I have proved is correct.

$$\left|\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n} +n} - \frac{1}{2} \right| = \left| \frac{2n - 2(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n)}{2(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n)} \right|< \left|\frac{2n - 2\cdot 2n}{2\cdot 2 n} \right|<\left|\frac{2n - 2n}{ 2 n} \right| =0<\epsilon\\\forall \epsilon>0$$

Can I do this way?

Comment: There are several algebra slips. It looks as if you are looking for a formal $\epsilon$-$N$ argument. Is that so?

Comment: Convergence, as $n$ tends to $\infty$?

Comment: Try using a test like the ratio test (it will be ugly) or show that the difference of the n term and n + 1 term approaches 0, just to verify that it converges at all. You can't pass to an inequality because you lose accuracy by doing that.

Comment: Don't just push symbols - think about the meaning of what you write.  You're claiming that the absolute value of something is strictly less than 0.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n} +n} - \frac{1}{2} \right| &= \left| \frac{2n - \left(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\right)}{2\left(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\right)} \right|\\\\
&= \left| \frac{n -\sqrt{n^2+n}}{2\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)} \right|\\\\
&= \left| \frac{n -\sqrt{n^2+n}}{2\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)}\frac{n +\sqrt{n^2+n}}{n+\sqrt{n^2+n}} \right|\\\\
&= \left| \frac{n^2 -(n^2+n)}{2\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)^2} \right|\\\\
&=\left| \frac{-n }{2\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)^2} \right|\\\\
&\le\frac{n}{8n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{8n}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>N=\lceil\frac{8}{\epsilon}\rceil$

Comment: Your thinking is correct, but there are some errors along the way. Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: How did you go from the second line to the third one?

Comment: We multiply numerator and denominator by $n+\sqrt{n^2+n}$.

Comment: I added two lines to show that.

Comment: @martycohen Thank you!! You  forgot to place the exponent $2$ on the denominator term.   I have edited so we are good now.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, your proof is incorrect because you lose accuracy by passing to an inequality. So no, you can't quite do it that way.

Comment: I don't believe that this answer is correct.  Are you familiar with the definition of a limit and $\delta-\epsilon$ proofs?